Having trouble when saving PDF as DOCX using VBA
The code should be simple enough, though it failed when trying to execute the SaveAs command. The error message said the file might be in use so it cannot be written.
The target directory has nothing but the PDF file itself, and it's not opened before the code was run. I have no idea what went wrong.
Sub PDFSaveAs()
    Dim AcroApp As Object, AcroAVDoc As Object, AcroPDDoc As Object, jso As Object
    
    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set AcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    
    If AcroAVDoc.Open("C:\Users\User\Downloads\123.pdf", vbNull) = True Then
        Set AcroPDDoc = AcroAVDoc.GetPDDoc
        Set jso = AcroPDDoc.GetJSObject
        jso.SaveAs "C:\Users\User\Downloads\123.docx", "com.adobe.acrobat.docx"
    End If
    
    AcroAVDoc.Close False
    AcroApp.Exit
    
    Set jso = Nothing
    Set AcroPDDoc = Nothing
    Set AcroAVDoc = Nothing
    Set AcroApp = Nothing
End Sub


Aren't there in Downloads any file, as you suggest? I am afraid, this cannot be true. The error description looks eloquent enough. Such a file must exist and being open in Word. If you do not see it, try opening Task Manger, look for Microsoft Word session and kill it (End Task).

@FaneDuru
That's the strangest part. I've tried to restart the computer and rerun the code, change the directory etc. yet problem consists. The code is supposed to be too simple to have any problem, sigh

The above code (of course, adapted for a specific path in my computer) works as it should. So, you maybe need to repair your Office installation...

@FaneDuru I've tested the code at home, it worked. Though at my workplace, the same problem consists, in every single computer. There must be something wrong yet I don't know

New finding: after I opened the PDF with the code, I stopped the code, manually save the PDF as DOCX, then continue to run the code to let it do the SaveAs one more time...guess what, no error this time. I'm even more puzzled right now. What's wrong?

I think, when you saved (As) the pdf, it already became .docx and saving .docx in .docx works, not being a matter of any conversion. Was AcroAVDoc being closed? Trying Debug.Print AcroAVDoc.GetFileNameȘ Stop just bellow the code line where you stopped the code. What does it return? A name with pdf extension or with docx?

What Office do you use at home and respectively, at work? Is it the same type?

@FaneDuru I figured out the answer myself. It's about the security setting in Acrobat. Thanks for all your replies and hopefully our discussion here might help someone in the future :)

I've read through all of the Preferences in Acrobat and figured the solution myself.
Preferences > Security (Enhanced) > Uncheck Enable Protected Mode at startup
Done! No more "file might be in use" error.
